# EditText actionNext doesn't work inside fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, focus

I have a fragment that contains `5 EditTexts`, first four have `actionNext` the last one has `actionDone`. I have a problem that when I am at the `4-th` EditText and press next in soft keyboard it removes focus from 4-th EditText and than the focus goes nowhere, the keyboard is still visible. When I press next button in keyboard the focus goes to the `5-th` EditText and than everything goes as it should.

**Problem**

When I am at the `4-th` EditText I have to press actionNext `2 times` in the keyboard to arrive at `5-th` EditText.

**The environment**

I am using AppCompatActivity, Support fragments, EditText is inside android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout, I use AndroidAnnotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have found the solution of this strange problem and I am posting it to help anyone with the same problem or find a better suggestion :)

My problem was related with fragments.

I have one activity with 2 fragments. When the activity is loaded it opens the first fragment with replace transaction

`mTransaction.replace(R.id...`

The first fragment has 2 EditText. When the user click a button in the first fragment the activity opens the second fragment that contains the 5 EditTexts where the bug happens. This is how I did the second fragment transaction:

```
mTransaction.add(R.id...
mTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mTransaction.commit();
```

And this is the problem because when the second fragment is committed I use `add` for the fragment transaction and this makes the first fragment to stay in the container, so this caused my bug.

In my opinion the EditText of first fragment was there and it gained the focus, even though in the second fragment I used `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/..."` (because I knew that EditText 4-th and 5-th had a problem) it didn't work.

**Solution**

The solution was very simple in my case, I had to make the second fragment transaction like this:

```
mTransaction.replace(R.id...
mTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mTransaction.commit();
```

If someone has a better suggestion is welcomed

**Second solution(2018):**

> For this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034391/disable-focus-on-fragment/53069798#53069798)

I solved this making a custom class for the parent `ViewGroup` of the fragment layout. In your custom ViewGroup you can override the method

`focusSearch(focused: View?, direction: Int)`

Adding this logic:

```
override fun focusSearch(focused: View?, direction: Int): View? {

        val focusSearch = super.focusSearch(focused, direction)

        if (direction == View.FOCUS_DOWN) when (focused?.id) {
            R.id.some_view_that_has_focus -> return new_view_focus
        }

        if (findViewById<View>(focusSearch.id) == null) {//the view found is not part of this parent return null
            return null
        }

        return focusSearch
}
```

When the new focused view is not part of this `parent` than return null. When some other Views focus is not reachable I manage it manually inside `when` cases.